# Calling variable from another function

Tags: function, python-3.x, variables, return, return-type

The function below gives me this error:

*"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'housebank' referenced before assignment"*

```
def placeBet(table, playerDictionary, bet, wager):
    playerDictionary['You'][1].add(bet)
    housebank -= (wager*table[bet][0])
    table[bet][1]['You']=wager
```

The housebank variable is declared in my main function below:

```
def main():
    housebank = 1000000
    table = {'7' : [9/1,{}]}
    playerDirectory = {'player1':[1,set(),True]}
    placeBet(table,playerDirectory, 10, 100)
```

How can I use *housebank* in the placeBet function?
If I do a **return** it will exit the main function, which I do not want to do...  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`housebank` is local to `placeBet`. There's three ways to do it that I can see:

- Make a class.

  ```
  class Foo:
      def __init__():
          self.housebank = 1000000
      def run():
          # ....
      def placeBet(....):
          # ....
          self.housebank -= (wager*table[bet][0])
          # ....

  def main():
      Foo().run()
  ```
- Declare `housebank` in a wider scope:

  ```
  housebank = 1000000
  def placeBet(....):
      # ....
  def main():
      # ....
  ```
- Make `placeBet` a closure inside `main`:

  ```
  def main():
      housebank = 1000000
      def placeBet(....):
          # ....
      # .... rest of main ....
  ```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what  I was looking for!